# Как создать пользовательские записи в wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Чтобы ссылки постов формировались из рубрик

```
 add_action( 'init', 'true_register_post_type_init' ); // Использовать функцию только внутри хука init

function true_register_post_type_init() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Функции',
        'singular_name' => 'Функцию', // админ панель Добавить->Функцию
        'add_new' => 'Добавить функцию',
        'add_new_item' => 'Добавить новую функцию', // заголовок тега <title>
        'edit_item' => 'Редактировать функцию',
        'new_item' => 'Новая функция',
        'all_items' => 'Все функции',
        'view_item' => 'Просмотр функции на сайте',
        'search_items' => 'Искать функции',
        'not_found' =>  'Функций не найдено.',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'В корзине нет функций.',
        'menu_name' => 'Кодекс WP' // ссылка в меню в админке
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true, // показывать интерфейс в админке
        'has_archive' => true, 
        'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/img/function_icon.png', // иконка в меню
        'menu_position' => 20, // порядок в меню
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'author', 'thumbnail')
    );
    register_post_type('functions', $args);
}
```

Comment: поясните суть вопроса. Что значит "ссылки постов формировались из рубрик"?

Comment: Возможно, вы имели в виду изменение формата постоянных ссылок для постов? Тогда ваш.сайт/wp-admin/options-permalink.php и https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks (%category%) вам в помощь.

Comment: @Ponio так у меня для обычных записей все нормально работает, а вот для пользовательского типа почему то нет, возможно для пользовательского типа нужно настроить свою таксономия?

Comment: Нужно, в массиве аргументов `$args` укажите `'taxonomies' => array('category')`. Но если вы до сих пор этого не сделали, то вы не могли добавлять записи типа `functions` в категории.